# AllowedPattern parameter behaviour apparently failing to match a simple regexp

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

In Cloudformation, I am validating parameter inputs using a simple `AllowedPattern`:

```
"ServicePassword": {
  "Description":           "Password for the AD service account",
  "Type":                  "String",
  "AllowedPattern":        "^."
},
```

The `variables.json` file contains a line (password redacted):

```
{"ParameterKey": "ServicePassword",  "ParameterValue": "E_redacted"},
```

(First letter a capital E; the remainder of the string redacted.)

When Cloudformation is called:

```
$ aws cloudformation create-stack --stack-name bastion_redacted --template-body file://Bastion.json --parameters file://variables.json --capabilities CAPABILITY_IAM --disable-rollback
An error occurred (ValidationError) when calling the CreateStack operation: Parameter 'ServicePassword' must match pattern ^.
```

I saw the same issue using an even simpler regexp that was just a string - `"AllowedPattern":        "hello"`.

If I simply remove the `AllowedPattern` line from the template, it works fine.

Is this a bug? Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The docs don't explicitly say this, but some of the examples seem to imply that these regexes are interpreted as if wrapped by `^` and `$`.  If that's true, the expression you're looking for would be more like `.+`.  If my speculation is right, this would be interpreted as `^.+$` ("contains one or more characters between beginning and end"), which appears to accomplish what you intended with `^.` ("begins with any one character", which I assume you meant as "non-empty").  Try `.+`?

Comment: Thank you, I figured it out. Yes, this is very confusing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CloudFormation [regexes](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/cfn-regexes.html) use [`java.util.regex.Pattern`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) for their syntax and behavior, so you can look to Java's documentation for a reference. The [`AllowedPattern`](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/parameters-section-structure.html#d0e17702) Parameters property requires the pattern to match the *entire* input string (not just part), or it will refuse the input.

The pattern `^` matches the beginning of a line, and `.` matches any *single* character, so your existing regex would match inputs like `x` or `0`. To match more than one character, you need to add a "greedy quantifier" such as `*` which will match any number of characters, or `+` which will match one or more characters. (Since `AllowedPattern` matches the entire string anyway, `^` isn't needed, so could be removed.)

Something like this should work as a simple regex matching any number of characters of any type:

```
"ServicePassword": {
  "Description":           "Password for the AD service account",
  "Type":                  "String",
  "AllowedPattern":        ".*"
},
```

Or you can use `".+"` for an equally-simple regex that matches one or more characters of any type.

Comment: Thank you, yes, I finally figured it out.

Comment: One problem here @wjordan is that `.*` also matches an empty string, with `*` meaning 0 or more of the preceding pattern. If non-empty is the intention, the pattern is `.+`.

Comment: Yes, actually `.*` would be the same as simply not using an `AllowedPattern` in the first place. The answer should be edited to read `.+ `.

Comment: This question asked how to construct a simple regex that validates the provided parameter input in CloudFormation, and `.*` sufficed. I've added `.+` to my answer per request. Note that neither regex is at all sufficient for your broader purpose of constructing a suitable regex pattern for ensuring adequate password input, but this is beside the point of this question.

Comment: I'm only concerned that a reader might incorrectly believe that `^.` (what I specified in my question) will have the same effect in other languages as `.*` in Cloudformation's idiosyncratic `AllowedPattern`.  Only `.+` is a correct translation. Thanks for your help though, and the great answer.